# stop inherit and add permission level is missing on subsite

Tags: permissions, sub-site, inheritance, custom-permission-level

I created site collection A and sub site B, site B inheritance has been stopped.

Now add permission level is missing on sub site B. permission level inherit form Site Collection A.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

Permission Levels are defined at the Site Collection level. Permission Levels are shared across all sites in the Site Collection. In an older version, maybe SP 2007, you could edit the Permission Levels from a subsite.

Comment: Actually, I delete site and create again my problem solved and I don`t know problem reason.